# Return value from Python to PHP is empty

Tags: python, php

My PhP code:

```
$privSeed ='irgendwelchenZufall';
echo "Seed:     " . $privSeed ."<br>";  
    
$privKey =hash('sha256', $privSeed);
echo "Private:  " . $privKey ."<br>";

#$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 /var/www/html/py/pubkey.py $privKey");
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 /var/www/html/py/pubkey.py 'c6676a262a177613e8d267c36b51740b6a349e30e3c2db0eb8da75a48664f925'");
$pubKey = shell_exec($command);
var_dump($pubKey);
echo "<br>";
echo "Public:   " . $pubKey;
echo "<br><br>";
```

My Python code:

```
import sys
#from bitcoin import privtopub, pubtoaddr
from bitcoin import *

pub = str()
print(pub)
print("Uebergabe:", sys.argv[1])

pub = privtopub(sys.argv[1])
print("Public:", pub)`
```

I also did another test script. If I add "from bitcoin import privtopub, pubtoaddr" or
"from bitcoin import *" to also in the test script I don't get a return value in PHP anymore.

If i run the same command at the console of my PI than it works:

> python3 /var/www/html/py/pubkey.py 'c6676a262a177613e8d267c36b51740b6a349e30e3c2db0eb8da75a48664f925'

reuslt:

> Uebergabe: c6676a262a177613e8d267c36b51740b6a349e30e3c2db0eb8da75a48664f925
> Public: 04d188511fb467def37d1fd1e9b14df0c1f23c19229fcce2dcaeaf5bbfbcaac3b8015116bab5d261e4f242f28158f69248b400ed3622e8c9997f53bc1d33083a65

What is wrong if I add "from bitcoin import privtopub, pubtoaddr" or
"from bitcoin import *" that after that PHP dont get a return value?